# How to show in tensorboard the tf.data.Dataset.map subgraph in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map), the `tf.data.Datasets` work in graph mode (in both eager and graph mode):

> Note that irrespective of the context in which map_func is defined (eager vs. graph), tf.data traces the function and executes it as a graph

In Tensorflow 1.X, we can easily plot this graph in Tensorboard: The processing functions are plotted in a subgraph.

For example,

```
def _parse_function(x):
    return x * 2

x = tf.constant([0 , 1])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

In Tensorboard, a subgraph appears, corresponding to the _parse_function:
[image]

However, in Tensorflow 2.0, this does not produce any visible element in the Tensorboard graph.
The following code does not produce any graph according to Tensorboard:

```
def _parse_function(x):
    return x * 2

logdir = 'logs'
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
x = tf.constant([0 , 1])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.trace_export(
      name="trace",
      step=0,
      profiler_outdir=logdir)
```

So, since a graph is created when calling the `map`, is there a way to access/visualize this graph?

Answer (score 0):

Create the ops inside a function and decorate it with tf.function

```
import tensorflow as tf
def _parse_function(x):
    return x * 2

@tf.function
def foo():
    x = tf.constant([0 , 1])
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

logdir = 'logs'
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)
foo()
with writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.trace_export(
      name="trace",
      step=0,
      profiler_outdir=logdir)
```